# iOS 5 NSURLConnectionLoader Thread Behavior After Segue

Tags: ios5, nsurlconnection, segue

In my ViewController, I am connecting to a web service to validate user credentials and waiting to see if they were valid. The NSURLConnection is executed from an IBAction button press:

```
// Executes after a successful connection and data download
-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    // Stop the spinners
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
    [aiSpinner stopAnimating];

    //Perform actions based on the status code
    switch(statusCode)
    {
            // Success
        case 200:
        {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueFromLogin" sender:self];
            break;
        }

            // Bad Request - incorrect POST parameters
        case 400:
        {
            // Display error
            break;
        }

        // Other cases

        default:
          break;
    }
}
```

When the next Story Board view is in the process of loading, the thread "Thread 6 com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader" is still active. Should I be concerned with this and is the proper way to execute method calls and segues after a connection is finished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like as soon as the next storyboard/view is loaded, all of the parent and child threads are cleaned up.